# How to extract the latest modified files?

Tags: python

I've got a list of file names including their dates, How can I extract the names based on their last date?

For example in the below picture which is the output of my code, two different set of files are shown, these files are backups with the same characteristics but different dates, I got the last modified dates from the system, But how to get the latest file name?

I should get the latest modified files like (based on picture output):

```
{'name': 'Switch-B2-109-Sep-22-08-55-20.581-55', 'date': '2020/09/22 08:55:29'}
```

And

```
{'name': 'Switch-B3-110-Sep-12-07-36-36-29', 'date': '2020/09/12 07:36:42'}
```

[output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZT6k.png)

So far, My code is this:

```
content = list(server.mlsd())
content.sort()
list = []

# print(content)
for f in content:
    if re.match('Switch', f[0]) or re.match('SW', f[0]):
        list.append({
            'name' : f[0],
            'date' : get_datetime_format(f[1]['modify'])
        })

length = len(list)

for i in range(length):
    print(list[i])
```

Files are being read through a backup server, so the associated dates would get change every day, I should take out the latest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is:

- first group the entries into different classes (by switch name)
- then do the sorting for each class (converting the datetime properly)

See the example below:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

content = [
    {'name': 'Switch-B3-110-Sep-12-07-36-36-29', 'date': '2020/09/22 07:36:42'},
    {'name': 'Switch-B3-110-Sep-12-07-36-36-29', 'date': '2020/09/12 07:36:42'},
    {'name': 'Switch-B3-110-Sep-12-07-36-36-29', 'date': '2020/09/15 07:36:42'},
    {'name': 'Switch-B3-110-Sep-12-07-36-36-29', 'date': '2020/09/1 07:36:42'},
    {'name': 'Switch-B1-110-Sep-12-07-36-36-29', 'date': '2020/09/22 07:36:42'},
    {'name': 'Switch-B1-110-Sep-12-07-36-36-29', 'date': '2020/09/12 07:36:42'},
    {'name': 'Switch-B2-110-Sep-12-07-36-36-29', 'date': '2020/09/15 07:36:42'},
    {'name': 'Switch-B2-110-Sep-12-07-36-36-29', 'date': '2020/09/1 07:36:42'}
]


# group by the switch name
data = {}
for f in content:
    # extract the switch name
    switch_type = re.match('^Switch-([A-Za-z0-9]+\-\d+).+$', f['name']).group(1)
    # initialize a new dictionary entry (if not exists)
    data[switch_type] = data.get(switch_type, [])
    data[switch_type].append(f) # append the item to it's group


# then do the sorting for each class
for switch, entries in data.items():
    sorted_entries = sorted(entries, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['date'], "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"), reverse=True) # sorting by date in reverse
    print(switch, '-', sorted_entries[0]) # then 0 index becomes the latest entry for this switch type
```

**output:**

```
B3-110 - {'name': 'Switch-B3-110-Sep-12-07-36-36-29', 'date': '2020/09/22 07:36:42'}
B1-110 - {'name': 'Switch-B1-110-Sep-12-07-36-36-29', 'date': '2020/09/22 07:36:42'}
B2-110 - {'name': 'Switch-B2-110-Sep-12-07-36-36-29', 'date': '2020/09/15 07:36:42'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort a list of dictionaries based on a key using sort method, pass `reversed = True` to get latest date first

```
from datetime import datetime
content = list(server.mlsd())
content.sort()
data = []

# print(content)
for f in content:
    if re.match('Switch', f[0]) or re.match('SW', f[0]):
        data.append({
            'name' : f[0],
            'date' : get_datetime_format(f[1]['modify'])
        })

length = len(data)

for i in range(length):
    print(list[i])

    
data.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['date'], "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"), reversed=True)

# to print latest date
print(data[0])
```

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

> Both list.sort() and sorted() have a key parameter to specify a
> function (or other callable) to be called on each list element prior
> to making comparisons.

PS: Avoid using `list` as variable name, it shadows builtin class `list`

Comment: Thank you for the reply and your time, But since I'm reading the files from the backup server, files are having different dates applied to them every now and then, how can I handle the new modified files and extract the last one which has the newest data?

Comment: @AliSri sort list by date in descending order will give you the latest entry as first element of the list. edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date string into real date and sort the list by date

```
from datetime import datetime

lst = [{'name': 'Switch-B2-109-Sep-22-08-55-20.581-55', 'date': '2020/09/22 08:55:29'},{'name': 'Switch-B2-109-Sep-22-08-55-20.581-56', 'date': '2017/09/22 08:55:33'},{'name': 'Switch-B2-109-Sep-22-08-55-20.581-57', 'date': '2020/09/22 08:55:38'}]
for e in lst:
  e['date'] = datetime.strptime(e['date'], '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
lst = sorted(lst,key = lambda e: e['date'])
print(lst)
```